# Gmail Api - Get Attachments

Tags: gmail, attachment, gmail-api, email-attachments

is it possible the get **all** the attachments for a specific message? 
i only find a [GET AttachmentById](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get)

Comment: The linked sample code shows how the get all `message.getPayload().getParts();` giving you a list containing all attachments as `MessagePart`s.

Answer (score 0):

First you get a list of your messages from a specific tag

```
            var re = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
            re.LabelIds = "Label_2";
            re.Q = "is:unread";
            var res = re.Execute();
```

Then you get the message through the id

```
               foreach (var email in res.Messages)
                {
                   GetAttachments(service, "me", email.Id, credPath);

                 }
```

Comment: SO is pretty much an English-only site. Even if your English is not perfect, Answers should still be in English.